# Firebase database rules, differentiate between create and update

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I want to differentiate somehow between creating or updating a list with write rules. Any user can create a new chat, while only a user inside that chat should be able to update it. So basically, I want to have an update rule that checks in another denormalized list if that user is inside that chat before being able to update (similar if not equal to the read rule which works fine) without breaking the `auth != null` rule for create new chat.

```
"chats": {
  "$chat": {
    ".write": "auth != null",
    ".read": "root.child('chats_by_user').child(auth.uid).child($chat).exists()"
  }
}
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An update usually means that [newData](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/security/database/#newdata) will be different from existing [data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/security/database/#data).

So the rule to only let the user update if he is inside the chat would be:

```
"newData.val() != data.val() &&  root.child('chats_by_user').child(auth.uid).child($chat).exists()"
```

And a create means that there is currently no [data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/security/database/#data) under that node.

So the rule to only allow create operations would be:

```
"!data.exists()"
```

Now putting it all together:

```
"chats":{
    "$chat":{
        ".write":"auth!=null && ((newData.val() != data.val() &&  root.child('chats_by_user').child(auth.uid).child($chat).exists()) || !data.exists() )",
        ".read":"root.child('chats_by_user').child(auth.uid).child($chat).exists()"
    }
}
```